# dynamic setState to add new dynamic property in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this scenario where I have to add multiple and dynamic property to an array of object. Says it's `lang = ['en', 'fr', 'more']`, how can I produce a object structure like this

Below is my failed attempt:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    lang: ["en", "fr"],
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        value: {
          en: "abc",
          fr: "hello"
        }
      }
    ]
  };
  onChange = (e, i) => {
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.map(o => ({
        ...o,
        value: {
          [this.state.lang[i]]: e.target.value //need fix
        }
      }))
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.lang.map((o, index) => (
          <div>
            <input
              onChange={e => this.onChange(e, index)}
              placeholder={o}
              type="text"
            />
            <br />
          </div>
        ))}
        <br />
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/p746jn313q

Comment: You might want to elaborate a little more. Are you trying to add new entries into the `items`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you're trying to do correctly, you just needed to spread the `value` object inside of your map:

```
onChange = (e, i) => {
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.map(o => ({
        ...o,
        value: {
          ...o.value,  // <- this
          [this.state.lang[i]]: e.target.value
        }
      }))
    });
  };
```

I've also edited the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/13vo5rrjwj

Comment: this approach worked but it's not perfect, because what if I allow user to change the langguages? it will keep the unmatched value, let me do a demo to address this issue.

Comment: I'm a little bit skeptic of the approach. You could just not have a `lang` array, and if needed to access all languages present you could use `Object.keys(items.value)`. I'll write a codepen in a bit.

Comment: Oh nevermind, `items` is an array. Let me find something better.

Comment: Let's say you have multiple `items`. Do you want the value in all of them to be affected by the input? That's the current behavior.